# QTP - VBScript to find a value/innertext of childobjects

Tags: child-objects

I'm trying to use childobjects method in QTP for WebTable where I have 38 cells with some values.

I'm able to get the number of childobjects i.e., count, but couldn't make use of it. Yes, actually what i'm trying to do is to find and select(ON) certain values out of 38 cells. But no where I could find some thread relevant to this need. Can someone help me in this, please?

Comment: Try using `For ... Each` to iterate through all the cells and select whichever is needed

Comment: Ya, actually I tried so. But couldn't make it clearly,,, i.e., how to select particular cell? actually, here in my requirement, i could differentiate the cells using 'innertext' property alone. Can you please share some example

Comment: Also, not sure if you can multi-select different cells. You can get the cell address though.

Comment: It will be more helpful if anyone can share me some sample for using GetROProperty or GetTOProperty with childobjects method.